# How can I use the return value in my next calculation

Tags: c#, oop

> The user enters the starting and ending meter readings for up to three meters. The application will calculate the KWH used for each meter and compute the total KWH Charge. Allow for  "meter roll".  Four dial meters have a maximum reading of 9999.  A meter "rolls" when it counts the KWH from from 9999 to 0000 and then begins counting normally again.  A meter has rolled when the ending reading is less than the beginning reading.  Make sure your application properly accumulates KWH for rolled meters.

below is my code am not sure how to use the return value on my next calculation here is the cal calculation `chargeKWH = totalKWH * KWH_Usage;`

```
public double count(int dialcount)
{
    dialcount = 4;

    while (dialcount > 0000 || dialcount < 9999) {

        totalKWH = meter1 + meter2 + meter3;
        dialcount++;
    }

    return totalKWH;
}

private void btnRecal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindFromUI();

    // calculate KWH and meter charge
    if (goodConvert) {

        meter1 = meter1e - meter1s;
        meter2 = meter2e - meter2s;
        meter3 = meter3e - meter3s;
        totalKWH = meter1 + meter2 + meter3;
        chargeKWH = totalKWH * KWH_Usage;
        meter_charge = meterCount * Meter_Charge;
    }
    else {
        errorMessage = "";
    }

    BindToUI();
}
```

Comment: You need to call your function for each meter then add the results. Something like `meter_charge = count(meter1) + count(meter2) + count(meter3);`. But I think you have other issues to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of your `count()` function.

You have two different calculations to perform, based on the whether the ending value is greater than or less than the starting value:

- If the ending value is greater than or equal to the starting value, then you
  simply subtract the start value from the end value.
- If the ending value is smaller than the starting value, subtract the start value from 9999, and then add the ending value; thus handling the "meter roll" thru 9999.

So for meter1, you'd use a simple `if/else` statement to run one of the calculations, whichever one is appropriate:

```
if (meter1e >= meter1s) {
    meter1 = meter1e - meter1s;
}
else {
    meter1 = (9999 - meter1s) + meter1e;
}
```

You'd repeat that structure for the other two meters, meter2 and meter3.

Afterwards you'd do your calculation as before:

```
totalKWH = meter1 + meter2 + meter3;
chargeKWH = totalKWH * KWH_Usage;
```